# Could I show a progress bar at notification bar in iOS 8

Tags: ios, notifications, local, custom-view

As we know, We can set string at notification bar in iOS, But i want to add a custom alert at notification bar, like download progress bar, the same as Android.
Is it possible?

Comment: There's no such control as "notification bar" neither at iOs or Android, you might want to clarify the question after you do a basic research on what controls are available to you.

Comment: I misnomer, let you misunderstand,My notification is the system notification. when you slide down the screen

Comment: This control is called Status Bar, the area below it is called Notification Center. You can display widgets and notifications at the Notification Center, AFAIK you can not add your own content to the Status Bar.

Comment: @RMW I want to achieve the same, have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can add any view to the notification bar, there are three section there `rightBarButtonItem`, `leftBarButtonItem` and `titleView` you can add any view to anyone of these view

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UIProgressView` ([Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/index.html)) and add it as a subview to the `UINavigationBar`. You can achieve something fancy by just costumizing it or use something like [LDProgressView](https://github.com/lightdesign/LDProgressView).